# How to avoid duplicate header on nested navigation in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, header, navigator

While implementing a custom sidebar navigator , i'm getting double headers. I've tried `headerMode: 'none'` as well as `header:null` , but no use.Following is some portion of my code

```
<View>
        <Header>
         <Button
              transparent
              onPress={() =>this.openMenu}
            >
              <Icon 
              style= {{color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 25, paddingTop:10}}
              name="bars" />
            </Button>
        </Header>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("CategoryDetail",{id:this.props.cat.term_id})}>
        {this.props.cat.term_id == '28' ? (<Text></Text>) : (

        <Card>
        .......
        ........
         .....
        ....
        ..
       </View>
```

also code for  nested navigator is

```
const StackScreens = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: LoginScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            header:null,

        }
    },
    RegisterForm: {screen: RegisterForm},
    CourseListing:{screen: CourseListing,
    navigationOptions:{
        header:null,

    }
    },
    Home:{screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    EconomicNews: {screen: EconomicNews},
    EconomicDetails: {screen: EconomicDetails},
    CategoryDetail: {screen: CategoryDetail},
    DetailedView: {screen: DetailedView},
    IndividualSection: {screen: IndividualSection},
    Mcq:{screen: Mcq},
    QASection: {screen: QASection},
    ForgotPassword: {screen: ForgotPassword,
    navigationOptions:{
        header:null
    }
    }   
})

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
   Home: {
     screen: StackScreens,

  },
  Profile: {
      screen: Profile
  },
  FAQ: {
      screen: Faq
  },
  LogOut: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
           tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {

               return Alert.alert(

                   'Do you really want to logout?',
                   [
                     {text: 'Accept', onPress: () => { navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoginScreen' }))

                     }},

                     {text: 'Cancel'}
                    ]

               );
           },
       })
  }
});
```

[image: This is what i'm getting]

Can't figure out this.What's the mistake?Please do help.

Comment: Is it your MainScreen or HomeScreen?

Comment: this is `HomeScreen` , which a user lands after logged in

Comment: In that case i cannot find a code where you have mentioned `header:none` for HomeScreen

Comment: Actually i deleted it ,coz there is no use.

Answer (score 2):

you can hide nested header passing { headerMode: 'none' } as a second argument in your nested StackNavigator.
Like that:

```
const RecentNav = StackNavigator({
   RecentScreen: { screen: RecentScreen }
}, {
   headerMode: 'none'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure adding headerMode:'none'  in the right place,

```
const StackScreens = StackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: LoginScreen,},
    RegisterForm: {screen: RegisterForm},
    CourseListing:{screen: CourseListing,},
    Home:{screen: HomeScreen,},
    EconomicNews: {screen: EconomicNews},
    EconomicDetails: {screen: EconomicDetails},
    CategoryDetail: {screen: CategoryDetail},
    DetailedView: {screen: DetailedView},
    IndividualSection: {screen: IndividualSection},
    Mcq:{screen: Mcq},
    QASection: {screen: QASection},
    ForgotPassword: {screen: ForgotPassword,}   
   },{

     headerMode: 'none', // <----- Add This Here !!

    });


export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
       Home: {
         screen: StackScreens,

      },
      Profile: {
          screen: Profile
      },
      FAQ: {
          screen: Faq
      },
      LogOut: {
          screen: LoginScreen,
          navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
               tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {

                   return Alert.alert(

                       'Do you really want to logout?',
                       [
                         {text: 'Accept', onPress: () => { navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoginScreen' }))

                         }},

                         {text: 'Cancel'}
                        ]

                   );
               },
           })
      }

    },{

        headerMode: 'none', // <----- Add This Here !!

    });
```

Give this Code a try !!

Comment: Actually when i tried by adding the code within `Container` now the screen appears with two headers each with a space and below it rest of the items will appear.